# Parse filename, rename file, then move to another directory

Tags: php, directory, filenames

I have a folder containing files named like this:
MDalarm_20201129_061408.mkv

I should rename them all like this:
dd_mm_yy_hhss.mkv
and then move them to a directory based on their date. example:
MDalarm_20201129_061408.mkv will become:

29_11_20_0614.mkv and will be moved to folder 29_11_20

```
$year = date("Y");
$month = date("m");
$day = date("d");
 
$directory = "$day_$month_$year";


if(!is_dir($directory))
{
    mkdir($directory, 755, true);
}

error_reporting(0);
$video=array();
$path= 'record';
$video=glob("$path/*.mkv");
$quanti=count($video);

foreach($video as $chiave => $nome)

{       
        $componenti=explode("_", $nome);
 }
```

Comment: Can you share your efforts with us?

Comment: And what's your question about this?

Comment: Your coding attempt doesn't seem to correlate to the requirements that you have expressed.  It is hard to understand where you got stuck.

Comment: Just loop over the files. During the loop just check if your directory exists (you already do that, but it needs to happen in the loop), use a regex to determine the date (you dont have to use a regex here, there are many ways to do it, especially if you have a format) and finally [rename](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rename.php) the file. If you have a specific problem come back here and ask.

Comment: not so come to recursively read and rename all files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is script to do that. I tried it on my Windows 10 and it is working well here

Edit: Now you just need to change the extension variable and it will process it fine

```
<?php 

$extension = "mkv";
$allFiles = glob("*.".$extension);

foreach($allFiles as $filename){
    $getYearDayMonth = getYearDayMonth($filename);
    if (!file_exists($getYearDayMonth)) {
        mkdir($getYearDayMonth, 0777, true);
    }
    $hhss = "";
    preg_match("/.*_(\d\d\d\d\d\d)\./",$filename,$hhss);
    $hhss = $hhss[1];
    file_put_contents($getYearDayMonth."/".$getYearDayMonth."_".$hhss.".".$extension,file_get_contents($filename));
}

function getYearDayMonth($filename){
    $getYearDayMonth = "";
    $getYear = "";
    $getMonth = "";
    $getDay =  "";
    preg_match("/MDalarm_(.+?)_/",$filename,$getYearDayMonth);
    $getYearDayMonth = $getYearDayMonth[1];
    preg_match("/\d\d\d\d/",$getYearDayMonth,$getYear);
    $getYear = $getYear[0];
    preg_match("/\d\d\d\d(\d\d)/",$getYearDayMonth,$getMonth);
    $getMonth = $getMonth[1];
    preg_match("/\d\d\d\d\d\d(\d\d)/",$getYearDayMonth,$getDay);
    $getDay = $getDay[1];

    return $getYear."_".$getMonth."_".$getDay;
}


?>
```